# Flow: POST using Send an HTTP request to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Trying to configure Flow to do a simple POST using **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint**. So far no luck, I get the following output:

"status": 400,
"message": "A type named 'SP.Data.WF_NotifierListItem' could not be resolved by the model.

Any suggestions?

[image]

**UPDATE**

After giving up on this a year ago I'm back for more punishment. Stumbled across a post that revealed method ListItemEntityTypeFullName to resolve type.

eg: _api/web/lists/getbytitle('WF_Notifier')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName

I've googled, read posts, tried several examples and variations, still no luck. It can't be that bloody hard to send a simple update request through Flow.

Here's my latest attempt, hard wiring the itemid until I get some kind of success. This results in:

*The parameter Title does not exist in method GetById*

[image]

Heres another variation using odata=verbose in Content-Type, attempting to declare metadata in body, and trying to update 'TestColumn' just in case it didn't like Title for some reason. This results in:

The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetById

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simply to use PATCH, not POST.

Answer (score 2):

Replace **'Title':'hello world**' with **Title:'hello world'**

**Always remember: Do not put '' on column name.**

A 400 means that the request was malformed.
[error code detail](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/)

Answer (score 0):

If you change your headers, you can get rid of the metadata attribute in your body.

By changing the `Content-Type` value to `application/json;odata=nometadata` you can simply send the body as

```
{
    "Title": "Hello World!"
}
```

and this should at least remove the error of the incorrect metadata flag.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After the Patch request successful updated the item, do you have a problem with more than 20 history-versions created for that item? (I checked and sure the http patch request sent only ONE time)

thanks